# After selecting row update database

Tags: jquery, mysql, css

I got a script that echo's database values and lets me highlight them. I have two problems with it. The first one is that the values are buttons while the highlight colors the whole area. I can't css so i don't have a clue how to fix that.

The second is the main question. After highlighting a row an clicking submit i want to update a table with the id of the row thats highlighted. Is this possible?

Here is my code (Yes i know it's a mess, i'm just testing stuff).

Thanks for looking at it :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.category_list li').click(function(){
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');

    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .highlight {background-color:yellow;}

    ul.category_list {
    margin: 35px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 12px Verdana;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul.category_list li a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #47a;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
    $sql = "select *
                                FROM sims"  ;
                        $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);       
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    ?>
    <form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <ul class="category_list">
    <li><a onclick="callGetApplicationDetails(0,0);" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $row['phonenr'];?></a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: quick note: open form before `include 'Includes/database_connection.php';`. Otherwise you will open form many times, and you close it only once.

Comment: Thank you, looked over that one

Comment: is your issue with the rendered HTML/CSS and not your php? If so can you post your rendered HTML/CSS with php includes removed?

Comment: Well the css is one of my problems so here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/VwbdP/. Normally the boxes dont overlap tough. Click it to see what i mean

Comment: Regarding your CSS problem, I'm not entirely sure what you need to "fix" - how do you need it to look in an ideal world?

Comment: Regarding your database problem, if I understand correctly, the way to do that is to wrap the whole list in a form, add a check box to each row (or `li`), giving each checkbox a `name` to build an array (e.g. `name="cb[0]"`,`name="cb[1]"` etc. Then, submit the form to a script that runs through the posted `cb` array to update the database accordingly.

Comment: Regarding my cs problem. In the ideal world the box should turn yellow instead of the entire background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your CSS problem? http://jsfiddle.net/UPNYN/

Simply modifying your jQuery to add an `a` to the selector:

```
$('.category_list li a').click(function(){
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Because previously you were targeting the `li` and not the `a` within it.

Then a quick rough-and-ready `!important` hack to your CSS:

```
.highlight {background-color:yellow!important;}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes it. Your answer regarding the database problem also helped me out quite a bit. So i think i'll manage right now.